# Demo Pre-Recorded JavaScript Functionality

Tags: javascript, demo

What is the best way to demo JavaScript/jQuery functionality?

Here is the situation, I would like to create a rough proof of concept for some functionality, but I want to pre-record it so that there is no chance of it messing up in the demo. If i had more time, I could develop a good working copy but time is short.

Ideally, I would like to include it in a PowerPoint.  I could do a high quality video, but was looking for alternatives.

Comment: don't you think best way is to write a simple code and run it?

Comment: the functionality isn't something that i could easily write to be robust.  If i had time to do that i would just write it...  I essentially want to be able to take shortcuts to get more of it demo'd and pre-record it so that i can show them what it could look like.

Comment: create a fiddle then?

Comment: it isn't that i don't have a platform to display the demo,  I could easily run JBoss or something.  I don't want the demo to mess up mid-presentation.  I'm not demoing a small piece of functionality like an animation, I want to demo a piece that will be complex with many parts as a pitch for months of work.  It isn't necessary for me to show it, but it would be more impressive if I had the visuals.

Comment: Sounds like what you'd like is some kind of screen capture software, which is off-topic for StackOverflow -- http://www.freetech4teachers.com/2012/09/17-free-tools-for-creating-screen.html